# Send mail using drupal_mail to cc and bcc

Tags: emails

I want to send mails using drupal_mail function but somehow it is sending mail only to To and that to without message body. Below is the code which I am using.

```
$params = array(
'body' => 'plain text mail',
'subject' => 'Join this Event',
);

if(drupal_mail('join_this_event', 'some_mail_key', "ansari@infiniti-research.com", language_default(), $params, "noreply@test.com", TRUE)){
  echo "mail sent";
 }
 else echo "unable to send";
```

Below is the hook_mail function of the module

```
function join_this_event_mail($key,&$message,$params) {
$language = $message['language'];
switch ($key) {
    case 'send_link':
        $message['subject']=t($params['subject'], $var, $language->language);
        $message['body']=$params['body'];
        $message['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed';
        $message['headers'] += $params['headers'];
    break;
}

}
```

How can this be resolved? and why is this happening

Comment: Can you post your join_this_event_some_mail_key() function? [Documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7) says that's what will be called to generate your message's body.

Comment: Hi Malot. Added the function in question. It is now sending the mail to cc and bcc but still mail body is empty.

Comment: If you will not **show** function's code, we will not be able to tell you what's wrong with her code.

Comment: Hi Malot. I have not implemented _key() function. Is it necessary to implement? If yes how can I implement it.

Comment: I linked docs in my first comment. This is not free code writing service. Read the docs, try, ask specific question about specific problem.

Comment: I know its not a free code writing service. I just asked a question. If you know then answer.

Comment: Answer is in the docs I linked on the first post. What's the point of duplicating it here?

Comment: Thanks Molot. But its written "A key to identify the e-mail sent. The final e-mail id for e-mail altering will be {$module}_{$key}.". This doesn't make much sense

Comment: well found the issue.                                Its $message['body'][]=$params['body']; and not            $message['body']=$params['body'];